# Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library missing

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2013

I tried to connect Microsoft Access 2013 with Visual Basic 6. Microsoft Access file extension use 2002-2003 file extension as a .mdb. But Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library missing in Visual Basic 6. How to add this library for program?

Answer (score 4):

DAO is ancient technology and it would be beneficial for you to move to ADO if possible. But assuming it's somebody else's world and you're just living in it ...

Copied directly from an MS KB article.

To redistribute DAO 3.6 with an application, complete the following three steps.

1. DCOM95 should be installed on Windows 95 systems that do not have DCOM installed. DCOM95 is distributed in a file called Dcom95.exe. A reboot of the system is required after installing Dcom95.exe. DCOM is required for the Mdac_typ.exe to work. DCOM is pre-installed on Windows 98 and Windows NT systems, so this step is only required for Windows 95.
2. Install Jet 4.0, which is installed as part of Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2.1 or 2.5, but is not included in MDAC 2.6.
3. Create a directory with the name DAO under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared and copy Dao360.dll to this directory. In addition, Dao360.dll must be registered as a COM DLL. This can be accomplished by using the Regsvr32.EXE utility.

I believe you can safely skip step 1.

[Complete KB reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/233002)

[How to obtain the latest service pack for the Microsoft Jet 4.0 Database Engine](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/239114)